# Python 3: Why does my class' function run twice?

Tags: python

I have a class which contains this attack function:

```
def attack(self, victim):
    strike = 0
    if victim.strength > self.strength:
        strike = 40
    else:
        strike = 70
    successChance = randint(1,100)
    if successChance > strike:
        self.lives -= 1
        return False
    else:
        victim.lives -= 1
        return True
```

It is only supposed to run once each time a user presses a button, however it runs twice meaning that every button press counts as two. I know the error is in my class function because the error occurs during test runs of the class.

The only code within the class which calls the function is my test function which only runs internally. Yet the problem persists in my GUI code.

This is my class function:

```
class Player(object):

def __init__(self, name="", lives=DEFAULT_LIVES):
    self._name = name
    self.lives = lives
    self.strength = randint(1,10)
    if self._name== "Test":
        self.lives = 1000
    if self._name== "":
        self._name = "John Smith"
def __str__(self):
    return (self._name +  " Life: " + str(self.lives) + " Strength: " + str(self.strength))

def getLives(self):
    return self.lives

def getStrength(self):
    self.strength = randint(1,10)
    return self.strength

def getName(self):
    return self._name

def isAlive(self):
    if self.lives <= 0:
       return False
    return True

def attack(self, victim):
    if victim.strength > self.strength:
        strike = 40
    else:
        strike = 70
    successChance = randint(1,100)
    if successChance > strike:
        print(successChance)
        self.lives -= 1
        return False
    else:
        print(successChance)
        victim.lives -= 1
        return True


def test():
    player = Player("Tyler")
    opponent = Player(choice(opponentList))
    while player.isAlive() == True and opponent.isAlive() == True:
        print(player)
        print(opponent)
        player.attack(opponent)
        player.isAlive()
        opponent.isAlive()
        if not player.attack(opponent):
            print("You lost")
        else:
            print("You won")
    print("Game Over")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: We have no idea; perhaps something calls it twice? The function itself does not call itself, we cannot tell from the function alone why it is being invoked two times.

Comment: As a quick note, you define `strike` in the main and `else` clause of the `if` statement, so there is no point defining it initially, as it will never be used.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your function and then check the stack (the series of method calls) to help you understand. If you can't have breakpoints in your environment try this print it. This reference might help you to print the stack: http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if looks like you're actually calling the function twice in test():

```
#your old code:
while player.isAlive() == True and opponent.isAlive() == True:
    print(player)
    print(opponent)
    player.attack(opponent) #called once here
    player.isAlive()
    opponent.isAlive()
    if not player.attack(opponent):#called 2nd time here
        print("You lost")
    else:
        print("You won")
print("Game Over")
```

I'd try this instead:

```
while player.isAlive() and opponent.isAlive():
    print(player)
    print(opponent)
    player_attack_was_successful = player.attack(opponent)
    #player.isAlive() #(does this line even do anything?)
    #opponent.isAlive()
    if player_attack_was_successful:
        print("You won")
    else:
        print("You lost")
print("Game Over")
```

Comment: thanks heaps. I didn't realize that it called the function from within an if statement